# Cairo: How to create path-warped text?

Tags: lua, cairo

I would like my text in Cairo to follow a drawn path. Something similar to [this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/behdad/3058628981/sizes/o/).

Now this link comes from [a post](http://lists.cairographics.org/archives/cairo/2008-November/015860.html) in the Cairo mailing list that claims to have coded this already. Only the link to the code is on `svn.gnome.org` which seems to have been taken down. My question is, does anybody know if this `cairotwisted` code referred to in the mailing list post is still around? If not, can somebody please give me some guidelines on how to do it?

I'm using the `lua` API to Cairo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears `cairiotwisted.c` that's being referred to in the mailing list is **[available here](https://github.com/phuang/pango/blob/master/examples/cairotwisted.c)** at github.